# When to kill redis client using NextJS?

Tags: redis

I'm using nextjs and redis cloud.  Right now, once it hits around 25. i manually go into redis insight and run

```
CLIENT KILL TYPE normal
CLIENT KILL TYPE slave
CLIENT KILL TYPE pubsub
```

Which will kill all but 3. How do i do this in code. I can't keep doing this when the site becomes live. But i'm not sure where to add the code.  I am using nextjs api. So i have